# The windows firewall on this machine is currently blocking remote debugging

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using MS-SQL server 2008 R2 express edition. In this when i am trying to execute my query i am getting the following error
"the windows firewall on this machine is currently blocking remote debugging.Remote debugging requires that the debugging be allowed to receive information from the network.Remote debugging also requires DCOM (TCP port 135) and IPSEC (UDP 4500/UDP500) be unblocked ".
what is this problem please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is really in your question.  Either allow the appropriate ports to be opened on the Windows Firewall or just disable the Windows Firewall altogether.

The 2nd approach would be my suggestion to you, only because it appears from your question, no offense meant, that you might not know how to get into Firewall to setup the port rules.

However, if you want to actually setup the port rules, etc. you can following this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126350.aspx

```
To disable the firewall:

To disable the firewall portion of Windows Firewall with Advanced Security by using the Windows Firewall Control Panel program

    Click Start, click Control Panel, click Network and Internet, and then under Windows Firewall, click Turn Windows Firewall on or off.

    On the General tab of the Windows Firewall Settings dialog box, select Off (not recommended), and then click OK.
```